# DropDownList com SelectList Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Pessoal estou tentando criar um Select List, mas no caso ele está retornando isso para minha view:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem

assim não está retornando os `Cargos` que estão no meu banco de dados [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e aqui estão os códigos que utilizo.

View:

```
@if (ViewBag.Office != null)
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Office", ViewBag.Office as SelectList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    <div class="input-group-append" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cadastra-cargo">
        <a class="btn btn-default">Adicionar</a>
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="Office" class="text-danger"></span>
}
else
{
    <select class="form-control" asp-for="Office">
        <option value="">Adicione um cargo</option>
    </select>
     <div class="input-group-append" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cadastra-cargo">
         <a class="btn btn-default">Adicionar</a>
     </div>
     <span asp-validation-for="Office" class="text-danger"></span>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(string returnUrl = null)
{
   ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

   var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

   if (user == null)
   {
       throw new ApplicationException($"Não é possível carregar o usuário com o ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
   }

   ViewBag.Office = _employeeManager.GetAllOfficeAsync(user.Id);

   return View();
}
```

Serviço GetAllOfficeAsync:

```
public SelectList GetAllOfficeAsync(Guid user)
{
    try
    {
        var lista = _context.FuncionariosCargo.Where(x => x.UsuarioId == user)
                                           .OrderBy(x => x.Cargo)
                                           .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                                           {
                                               Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                                               Text = c.Cargo
                                           });

            SelectList result = new SelectList(lista);



            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Deixa ver se entendi seu problema, você está clicando no adicionar e não está atualizando a dropdown? Ou o Dropdown não está criando um selectlist-item?

Comment: O Dropdown não está criando um selectlist, ele está colocando aquela mensagem conforme a imagem que coloquei na pergunta.

Comment: Matheus, existe esse using na sua controller?
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

Comment: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering; está na pasta `Services`, aonde busco os dados.

Comment: Existe a possibilidade do retorno do seu select estar vindo em branco? (não consigo abrir a imagem pois estou no trabalho)

Comment: Pior que já fiz esses testes ele está retornando os valores corretamente.

Comment: O erro está em `GetAllOfficeAsync`, ele está buscando os dados corretamente, mas quando da o return `result`, ele substitui os dados.

Answer (score -1):

Matheus, no seu método: `GetAllOfficeAsync`

Adiciona uma validação para retorno da sua listagem, se voltar uma lista em branco, passe `Null` ao invés de passar a Lista.

Tente fazer assim:

```
    public SelectList GetAllOfficeAsync(Guid user)
{
    try
    {
        var lista = _context.FuncionariosCargo.Where(x => x.UsuarioId == user)
                                           .OrderBy(x => x.Cargo)
                                           .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                                           {
                                               Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                                               Text = c.Cargo
                                           });

            SelectList result = new SelectList(lista);

        if(result.count > 0)
        {
           return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: é que no caso ele retorna `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem` para o Controller,

Comment: @Matheus tenta fazer essa validação antes